# Vectorized way to add elements using an index map?

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I have two `numpy` arrays, one of size `(386, 3, 4)` and another of size `(386, 4)`, which I will call `values` and `keys` respectively. The second array contains integers which are indices to my output array. I need to implement the following `for` loop -

```
for i in range(386):
    for j in range(4):
        output[keys[i, j]] += values[i, :, j]
```

Of course, `output` has dimensions `(max_index + 1, 3)`. Could I make way with a vectorized implementation?

Comment: Soooo `output` is a dictionary, or not? Why the scare quotes?

Comment: `output` is another numpy array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `np.add.at` should do what you want:

```
np.add.at(output, keys, np.transpose(values, (0, 2, 1)))
```

Small array example:

```
values
# array([[[100, 200, 300, 400],
    [ 10,  20,  30,  40],
    [  1,   2,   3,   4]],

   [[500, 600, 700, 800],
    [ 50,  60,  70,  80],
    [  5,   6,   7,   8]]])
keys
# array([[4, 0, 3, 1],
   [1, 0, 2, 2]])
out
# array([[0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0]])
np.add.at(out, keys, np.transpose(values, (0, 2, 1)))
out
# array([[ 800,   80,    8],
   [ 900,   90,    9],
   [1500,  150,   15],
   [ 300,   30,    3],
   [ 100,   10,    1]])
```

Answer (score 1):

**Approach #1**

Here's one approach using [`np.tensordot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html) -

```
# Store size param         
n = values.shape[0]

# Get mask for mapping each key to corresponding row in o/p array
# Simply put : mask = keys==np.arange(n)[:,None,None]        
r,c = np.indices(keys.shape)
mask = np.zeros((keys.max()+1,n,keys.shape[1]),dtype=bool)
mask[keys,r,c] = 1

# Finally mask and sum reduce elems off values
out = np.tensordot(mask, values, axes=((1,2),(0,2)))
```

---

**Approach #2**

Here's another with [`np.add.reduceat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html) after sorting the columns based on the `keys` -

```
n,nr = values.shape[:2]        
kr = keys.ravel()
sidx = kr.argsort()
krs = kr[sidx]
v = values.transpose(1,0,2).reshape(nr,-1)[:,sidx]

cut_idx = np.r_[0,np.flatnonzero(krs[1:] != krs[:-1])+1]
out = np.zeros((keys.max()+1,nr))
out[krs[cut_idx]] = np.add.reduceat(v, cut_idx, axis=1).T
```

Comment: Thank you, but @PaulPanzer's approach seems to be a lot easier